# Android: notification from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I have an alarm manager that starts a broadcast receiver.
Here is my broadcast receiver:

```
public class AlarmBrodcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MyActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(0)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }  
}
```

The broadcast starts in time, but there is no notification, only sound. Where is the text? What's wrong? Is it because I'm using API 10 and the support library?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Oh, I found the problem. The problem is in .setSmallIcon(0)...When I set some real resource, its ok, notification appear...

Comment: I didn't have your specific problem, but thanks to you I managed to be sure this was possible to do in my API level.