# Should my broadcast receiver be a static inner class or a separate class?

Tags: android, background, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I am busy working on a daily quote app. I have a ListView inside of my MainActivity class that displays one daily quote from a local SQLite Database. That works. I need it to change the quote that it is displaying each day at 9:00 a.m. plus send a push notification to the user at that time. I need the notification to go if the app is closed for the purpose of bringing the user to the app. The ListView can be updated when the user opens the app, they won't know the difference.

I am having problems with broadcast receiver and alarm manager.

I currently have my BroadcastReceiver as an inner class inside of my MainActivity. I did this in order to run the method that populates the ListView, which is in the MainActivity, from the BroadcastReceiver. However, I have my receiver registered and unregistered in the code, not in the manifest. This causes it to run each time the activity is created causing the ListView to populate each time as well defeating the purpose because I only need it to change and a notification to be sent each morning at 9:00 a.m.

I have tried making the broadcast receiver static and then registering it in the manifest but then I have all sorts of problems referencing non-static stuff from the static class. I have also tried making the receiver a separate class outside of the MainActivity class but then I can't call my method that populates the ListView inside the MainActivity from the receiver class. It seems like a no-win but I know that's not the case. It's currently registered in onCreate. I have tried onStart, onResume, etc... it works the same way. I just don't know what to do.

I don't have the push notification code in there yet I am still working on it.

Here is my code:

MainActivity (relevant portions):

Method to populate the ListView:

```
public void DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess(){

SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper = new SQLiteAssetHelper(this, 
DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
SQLiteDatabase SqlDb = sqLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM dailyQuoteTable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 
1";
Cursor cursor = SqlDb.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
DailyQuoteCursorAdapter DQCursorAdapter = new DailyQuoteCursorAdapter(this, 
cursor);
this.mDailyQuoteListView.setAdapter(DQCursorAdapter);
}
```

Here I register the alarm dynamically in the MainActivity's onCreate method:

```
mTodaysQuoteReceiverStaticInnerClass = new 
TodaysQuoteReceiverInnerStaticClass();
IntentFilter filter = new 
IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
this.registerReceiver(mTodaysQuoteReceiverStaticInnerClass, filter);
```

Here is my receiver class (which I made an inner class in the MainActivity):

```
public class TodaysQuoteReceiverInnerStaticClass extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent){

PopulateTodaysQuote();

}
}
```

Here is the method that sets my alarm. I call this method from the onCreateMethod in the MainActivity:

```
public void todaysQuoteAlarm(){

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (currentTime <= calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, 
TodaysQuoteReceiverInnerStaticClass.class);
        int ALARM1_ID = 10000;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 
ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }
    else{
```

Comment: use a Broadcast receiver in separate class and register in Manifest, it should work

Comment: Thank you, bk7. When I do that, I am unable to call the method that I need to run that is located in the main activity. This is the DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess() method listed above. Any advice on how to call that from the seperate broadcast receiver and have it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

you can use broadcast receiver in the separate class and start a notification from there [notification from broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924835/android-notification-from-broadcastreceiver). I believe that you want to execute  DailyQuoteDatabaseAccess() method when user will opens the application. I suggest you to maintain a separate table for today's  quote and in the broadcast receiver update the today's quote table (assuming that you want change a quote once in a day) and fetch the data from Today's Quote Table to show the data in list view.

Comment: Thanks again. I am going to try to do that and I will let you know what happens.